# DXL script to change specific words in strings to italic

Tags: scripting, requirements, ibm-doors

I'm new to DXL and learning. I want to check in modules for all attributes for certain words to change them to italics.

Example:

specific word = change

before DXL script in attribute/column A: "This requirement should change"

after DXL script in attribute/column A: "This requirement should *change*"

**Code snippet**

```
for itemRef in f do
{

if(shType=="Formal")
      {
        filtering off;    
        m = read(fullName(itemRef), false)          
        Object o
        for o in m do 
       {

       //Operation for changing words to italic


       }

        close(moduleReference);
      }
}
```

**Updated Code**

```
void ChangeItalic()
    {

      Module m = current
      filtering off;          
      Object o
      for o in m do
    {
      int i, j

      string t = o."Object Text" 
      string ModuleName = m."Name"
      string ObjectName = identifier(o)
      print ModuleName "\n"
      print ObjectName "\n"
      print t

      if(matches("[Ll]astenheft",t)){
        print "changed" "\n"
        i = start 0
        j = end 0
        t = t[0:(i-1)] "\\i " t[match 0] "\\i0 " t[j+1:]
        o."Object Text" = richText t


      }

}
}

// Main-Method
void main(void)
{

  ChangeItalic();

}
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the "guts" of your script:

```
Object o = current
int i, j
string t = o."Object Text"
if (matches("[Cc]hange", t)){
    i = start 0
    j = end 0
    t = t[0:(i-1)] "\\i " t[match 0] "\\i0 " t[j+1:]
    o."Object Text" = richText t
}
```

this script will operate on the current object and change the word "change" to Italic if it is within the Object Text.it would be different if you wanted to display only.

Unfortunately, I don't know if you are wanting to *display* the word in italics (in a column) or to change the word to italics in the attribute.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Sorry for answering late. Your suggestion works perfect! One problem is that if the word to be changed appears more than once, only the first word is changed to italic.